# How to access value in object with '=>'?

Tags: javascript

I got response looking like this:

```
Map(1) {
  'n:0' => {
    info: {
      type: 'internal',
      ihrDisabled: true,
      bounce: true,
      bounced: false,
      value: 5
    }
  }
}
```

How to access field `value`? Honestly I never saw that before and always get `undefined`.

Comment: That's just the console printing the content of a map object. You access it the same way as any map object: `m.get(yourKeyHere)`

Comment: It's just how the console shows entries of a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). Use the [get](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get) method to retrieve the content, like `yourMap.get('n:0')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is how your console displays a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). You access elements of a Map using the [`get()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get).

```js
// Create a Map the same as the one given.
// It has one element, with the key 'n:0' and the value an object.
const map = new Map()
map.set('n:0', {
  info: {
    type: 'internal',
    ihrDisabled: true,
    bounce: true,
    bounced: false,
    value: 5
  }
})

// Log the wanted property.
console.log(map.get('n:0').info.value)
```